# SharePoint - Find user access to sites

Tags: 2007

Is there a way to find what sites a user has access to in a SharePoint farm?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allusers(v=office.12).aspx

You can crawl each site in the site collection, and then check all users.